# Test REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING even though field is set?

Tags: apex, unit-test, dml

```
@isTest
private class Test_ordinefermo {

    @isTest
    static void test_newAttachment(){
        test.startTest();
            Opportunity op= new Opportunity();
            op.Name= 'abc';
            op.StageName='Open';
            op.Trattativa__c = 'Automotive';
            op.CloseDate = date.valueOf('2017-11-12');
            op.Tipo_di_Trattativa__c = 'Cross Selling';
            insert op;
            file_ordine_fermo__c fofc = new file_ordine_fermo__c();
            fofc.Name = 'fofcdemo';
            fofc.Trattativa_Correlata__c =op.Id;
            insert fofc;
            ApexPages.StandardController std = new ApexPages.StandardController(fofc);
            ordinefermo ord= new ordinefermo(std);
            ord.newAttachment();
        test.stopTest();
    }
}
```

I have above test class testing a extention `ordinefermo`. when I try to test `newAttachment()` method is giving me

> System.DmlException: Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first
>   error: REQUIRED_FIELD_MISSING, Required fields are missing:
>   [Trattativa_Correlata__c]: [Trattativa_Correlata__c]

But I have already populated `Trattativa_Correlata__c` field in my test class.
When I try to deleting the statement `ord.newAttachment();` the test case is being successful but I am falling behind code coverage as I am not testing the method.

Comment: did you check all workflows, processes, triggers on Opportunity? Seems like some automation tool clear value of `Trattativa_Correlata__c` field. Can you highlight line, where this exception occurs ?

Comment: what is the Data Type of "Trattativa_Correlata__c" field?

Comment: It is a master look up to an opportunity object

Comment: @AlexanderBerehovskiy ord.newAttachment(); is the line where Iam getting the error

Comment: @prasad and what about code of class under test ? what `newAttachment` is actually doing?

Comment: public PageReference newAttachment(){
        string idopt =  ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('idopp') ;
        list <file_ordine_fermo__c> lis = [select id from file_ordine_fermo__c where trattativa_correlata__c=:idopt ];
        if (lis.size()==0) {
        ford.Trattativa_Correlata__c=idopt;
        system.debug('sono la tratt corr:' +ford.Trattativa_Correlata__c);
        ford.name='CONFERMA ORDINE';
        insert ford;            
        } else {
             
            some error
            
            return null;
        }
    }

}

Comment: Please **[edit]** our post to add any clarifications (especially code). That's not what comments are for.

Answer (score 1):

Id for the opportunity is not passed to controller. Your method is getting id from apex page parameter. So you need to pass opportunity id to your page. Try this in your test method before calling `newAttacment()`:

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('idopp',op.id);
```

Comment: @prasad Did it work ?